# How to incorporate responsive background images that exceed browser height?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive

I have a background image that exceeds the height of the browser. How might I incorporate the image so that I can scroll down to see the remaining portion while maintaining the scale across different browser sizes? Code that I have written or used only clips the image to fit the size of the browser. Overflow seems to have no affect. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the end result you're looking for, here are some approaches and tools you could consider.

- because of the different aspect ratios of desktop and mobile screens, it's sometimes difficult to have a single background image that will work well for everyone. But if you prepare a desktop background image of say 1920px wide by 1080px high, and a mobile background image of say 640px wide by 960px high, you can use media queries to specify different backgrounds for different viewports.
  more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Resizing_background_images

```css
@media(max-width:480px){ 
    body{
       background-image:URL(mobile-background.jpg);
    }
 }

@media(min-width:481px){ 
    body{
       background-image:URL(desktop-background.jpg);
    }
}
```

- background image size of cover or contain are also really useful. Specifying **contain** means that the background image will be scaled to fit the size of the element it's applied to.

And specifying **cover** means that it will fill the background of the element it's applied to, and you should expect some croping of the background image. You can also position the image.
more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

```css
div{  
   background-size: contain;  
   /* or */
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
}
```

- and sometimes you might want to stop the background from scrolling:
  more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

```css
div{
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```